# No effect after editing grub.cfg & updating it

Tags: 10.10, boot, grub2

I've reached a dead end in this matter & I was wondering if someone out there could help me out.

I located the grub file located in etc/default and edited it following reliable instructions. After I do & run the `sudo update-grub` & reboot, nothing changes & it stays the same.

I even have an application called "start-up manager" to simply adjust let's say the time-out, sadly that didn't work either.

Could someone help me out?

Note: I do have this thing called burg to have a GUI when booting, but even before I installed it the problem was there.

Here's my grub.cfg:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" vga=775"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Files in etc/grub.d:
00_header, 05_debian_theme, 10_linux, 20_linux_xen, 20_memtest86+, 30_os-prober, 40_custom, 41_custom, readme

boot/grub/grub.cfg

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/538608/

Comment: What version of ubuntu you are using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 (kernel 2.6.35-22)

Comment: Please provide a list of files in /etc/grub.d and post the contents of any "*_custom" file in that directory. Please also add the contents of /boot/grub/grub.cfg so we can see if the settings from /etc/default/grub you posted are reflected in grub's config file. (I guess it's ok to link to http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ if things are too long ;))

Comment: Updated the question just now. Please check it.

Comment: Hm, weird, you should have recovery entries with above config file. Did you manually edit the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file? Move it and re-run update-grub: `sudo mv /boot/grub/grub.{cfg,back} ; sudo update-grub` and look if there are recovery entries. (Note: if you don't want those, just uncomment `#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"` in the /etc/default/grub file and run update-grub again.) Else, everything looks fine - your 1 second boot delay is there (although I don't know if that value isn't a bit too low).

Comment: No I haven't manually edited the original grub.cfg, I knew that it's risky..
(I tried to uncomment it to eliminate the recovery option, but it didn't work either.)

As I said I do have that thing called "burg" as a GUI interface for the grub loader..but I'd that problem before I installed it, so I guess it had nothing to do with it.

Comment: What is the output of "sudo update-grub"?

Comment: It updates normally, no errors.

Comment: You could make it more clear that you are using burg.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris I already highlighted it, read my question thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution people. It seems that because of "burg" I must make changes to the burg file located in etc/default. And then run `sudo update-burg`.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you have located the file `grub` in `/etc/default` but the file you have pasted above is `/etc/grub/gruf.cfg`.

Are you sure that you are editing the right file?  `/etc/grub/grub.cfg` is an auto-generated file and it will update from configuration in other files whenever you run `update-grub`. You need to make changes into `/etc/default/grub` for them to take effect.

What I think is happening at the moment is that you change `/etc/grub/grub.cfg` and then you run `update-grub`, which reverts your changes, and then when you reboot you don't get what you want. Please try changing `/etc/default/grub` and then let us know what the output is.

Comment: What I posted is indeed the grub file located in /etc/default...but the "pastebin" link shows my /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Read the question thoroughly.

Comment: My bad but you have written "Here's my grub.cfg:" just above the pasted file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true` to false?

Comment: Yup, this worked once, then stopped again..I'm seriously sick with it =S

Answer (score -1):

Here is the process step by step:

```
sudo -i                             gives root access

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub        gedit is editor 

GRUB_DEFAULT=X                      Change depending on order of boot eg 3
                                        where numbering starts with 0.
```

Save file and run the following from the terminal.

```
sudo update-grub                    updates file
```